# I am getting pushwoosh response null

Tags: android, push-notification

I have integrated pushwoosh in android application (not in titanium)..
I am successfully getting notification also..

My issue is,

Text is displayed on notification area which I passed from woosh..
BUT NOT ABLE to extract it from intent
intent.getExtras().getString(PushManager.PUSH_RECEIVE_EVENT)

Also my notification does not remain on notification area..
it only displayed once and disappear, I am not able to click on that 
because it is not staying there..as like other notification..!!??

Please can anybody suggest any thing..?

Comment: Please post your code for displaying the notification.

Comment: I coded as per pushwoosh config guide
http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-push-notification-sdk-configuration-guide/
(I checked and compare 3-4 times that is there anything remain, but I implemented same as given by them, nothing missing..)

Comment: //in onCreate and start push manager
  PushManager pushManager = new PushManager(this, APP_ID, SENDER_ID);
  pushManager.onStartup(this);

Then 
//Re-register receivers on resume
     registerReceivers();
  pushManager.setVibrateNotificationType(VibrateType.ALWAYS);
  pushManager.setSoundNotificationType(SoundType.ALWAYS);
  pushManager.setLightScreenOnNotification(true);

Answer (score 0):

For notification to remain on the notification bar there is falg to set in Android Notification.

```
Notification not= new Notification(R.drawable.icon,title+" "+context.getString(R.string.Start_in),System.currentTimeMillis());
not.flags=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
```

For Android Notification there is One falg to Clear the notification or not. So I think there will some flag to Not clear the Notification when it arrives.
    So Try to find out the flag for not clearing the Notification.
    As you are setting flag for sound

```
pushManager.setSoundNotificationType(SoundType.ALWAYS);
```

Comment: In pushwoosh they are not providing to create object of Notification, so we can not set Flag..
But I find another way, when receive PushNotification from pushwoosh, I handle it using own (custom) Notification using NotificationManager..
In short we have to combine pushwoosh + own Notification object